# Can I list source for already defined bash functions?

Tags: git, bash

A accidentally some changes to my bash configuration I keep in git by doing git reset --hard head in an incorrect directory. In particular some nifty functions I used. I have a terminal running which still has these functions loaded, can I still reconstruct them from the environment somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you defined them as functions in a file your sourced from something like `.bashrc` or `.profile` you should be able to use bash's `type` command.

```
$ type your_nifty_function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ declare -f
```

will list *all* functions defined in the current shell.

Comment: +1 but `declare -f functionname will just print out the specific function with no other decoration.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare
```

`declare` will print out all the functions defined. (And all environment variables as well).

```
alias
```

`alias` will print out all aliases defined.